# Laravel8 realizando mi primer registro de usuario

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Hola quisiera que alguien me apoyara en laravel 8 soy nuevo y apenas estoy practicando y tomando cursos por mi cuenta, necesito capturar a mi base de datos un formulario para registrar usuario.

todo bien hasta el momento pero no logro avanzar por un error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradeceria que me apoyaran al parecer el error esta cuando :
$registro = new registro();

saludos

Comment: El error te esta indicando claramente el problema, ¿Qué es "registro"?

Comment: Yo se q es registro la del problema pero como ewtoy iniciando alguien me puede dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo correctamente.

Comment: Tiene que importa tu clase registro, para ello, puedes hacer `use App\Models\Registro`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu apoyo @tecnobyte fuiste muy claro. te califico 500/100. gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
$usuario = new registro;
```

Estas *intentando* crear una instancia de la clase registro que *asumo* es el modelo asociado a una tabla de nombre similar en tu base de datos.

Entonces *necesitas importar* dicha clase al contexto de tu controlador por medio de su namespace completo, (*dado las carpetas que veo asumiré que usas Laravel 8*), luego entonces se hace de esta forma:

```
use App\Models\Registro;
```

- **`App`** (*claramente su contexto e importancia es mas amplia pero se escapa de esta pregunta, recomiendo [leas a detalle aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-root-app-directory)*)
- [**`Models`** esta referido a la carpeta](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#models-directory) donde se almacenan desde Laravel 8 cada clase modelo
- **`Registro`**, será el nombre de la clase asociada  a una tabla en tu base de datos con un nombre similar (*aunque no estrictamente, recomiendo leas a **detalle** las [convenciones de modelos de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)*)
- Como comentario final, te recomiendo cheques a detalle los nombres de tus archivos, pues no será lo mismo `registro` que `Registro`, identifica que estás usando.

Y ahora si tu instancia queda de esta forma:

```
$usuario = new Registro();
```

**Referencias**

- [**PSR-12 Clases, propiedades y métodos**](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#4-classes-properties-and-methods)
- [Espacios de nombre en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.rationale.php)